# greedy regex for one part, non-greedy for other

Tags: r, regex

I'm using regex in R but I want it to be greedy for the left part and non-greedy for the right part. Suppose I want to extract the text between the words "left" and "right", but I want it to be greedy and keep looking for the word "left" in the text until it finds the last occurence. However, I also want it to be non-greedy for "right" and stop at the first occurence. How do I change this code?

`gsub(".*left(.*)right.*", string)`

As an alternative, I stored positions of words using `regexpr` in R, is it possible to use regex between position x and position y?

Answer (score 3):

If the regex in R are Perl-compatible, adding a ? behind a * (or +) makes that part non-greedy:

```
Input: aaaabaaaaab
Regex: `/a*?b/` 
Result: aaaab
```

Comment: What if I have `aaaabbbbb` and I just want `ab`? i.e. I want it to be greedy on a and non-greedy on b.

Comment: Then just say /ab/ or /a+?b+/

Comment: Or even greedy in a non-greedy regex statement

Answer (score 3):

```
string <- "A left bat ran after a left dog who is right but not too right."
gsub("^.*left(.*?)right.*$", "\\1", "string)
```

The pattern `.*left` will greedily consume everything until the *last* occurrence of `left`, and the pattern `(.*?)right` will consume everything until the *first* occurrence of `right`.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Doesn't that return `bat ran after a left dog who is`? What if I want `dog who is`?

Comment: This returns `dog who is`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative here would be to use `stringi` package. The functions `stri_replace_last` and `stri_replace_first` do exactly what you need, i.e. (Using `string` from @Tim's answer),

```
library(stringi)

stri_replace_first(stri_replace_last(string, '', regex = '.*left '), '', regex = ' right.*' )
#[1] "dog who is"
```