# Extracting speaker interventions from a text using R? Or something else?

Tags: r, text-mining

We're working on a text mining project for school on the proportion of environment-oriented speech in Quebec's National Assembly. We wanna extract a list of every speaker's interventions throughout the years.

Our documents are all formatted this way:

```
Mr. Smith : Blablabla

Mrs. Jones : Blablabla
```

What I would like to do is write the simplest thing possible that would allow me to extract these interventions. I'm thinking something along the lines of:

*"Every time you see [Mr. **** : ] OR [Mrs. **** : ], extract ALL the text until you see another occurrence of [Mr. **** : ] OR [Mrs. **** : ]. And, ideally, extract all the Mr. Smiths and the Mrs. Joneses and the Mr. Williams in separate files while keeping track of which file the interventions came from.*

I started writing a very basic `gsub` line which allowed me to replace the occurrences I wanted to replace with an @, only to realize I don't want to replace them completely but rather maybe just add an `@` in front which would probably make it easier to write something that would just separate the @s in distinct files.

```
gsub("(Mr.|Mrs.)\\s\\w*\\s:\\s", "@", test)
```

I've just started teaching myself R for this project and I need some insight on how I should proceed next. Or should I use something else instead?

Comment: Probably tokenize words and then `cumsum(grepl(...))`, like how chapters are IDed here: https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html#tidyausten

Comment: Can you provide a link to an actual document?

Comment: The "." you use in your regex is actually a metacharacter; as a metacharacter it does not mean "period" but "anything". If you do want to include the period in your regex as a period you have to escape it thus: "\\."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to replace the speaker names, you can use what is called 'positive look ahead', like this:

```
# some example data:
bla <- c("Mr. X : blablabla bla bla bla. Mrs. Y : bla bla blablablab Mr. XY : bla bla balblabla blabl abl" )

# replace with look ahead:
gsub("(?=(Mr.|Mrs.))", "@ ", bla, perl = T)
"@ Mr. X : blablabla bla bla bla. @ Mrs. Y : bla bla blablablab @ Mr. XY : bla bla balblabla blabl abl"
```

The @ is a good starting point for extracting the individual interventions. This can be done thus:

```
pattern <- "@.[^@]*" 
matches <- gregexpr(pattern, bla)
interventions <- regmatches(bla, matches)
interventions <- unlist(interventions)
interventions
[1] "@ Mr. X : blablabla bla bla bla. "      "@ Mrs. Y : bla bla blablablab "         "@ Mr. XY : bla bla balblabla blabl abl"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I had to work a bit on my regex so it only caught what I needed, but your lines for extracting the interventions worked perfectly! Now my colleague and I may proceed to the next step, which is extracting the interventions into separate files for each speaker. We'll try to find it out by ourselves but if you have any idea of how we should proceed, feel free to guide us :)

Comment: You can proceed thus: 1. split interventions into 2 columns (1 for speaker ID, 1 for intervention) using the package `stringr`:
`require(stringr)`
`dat <- data.frame(
  speaker_name = str_extract(interventions, "@.*[a-z|A-Z].*:"), 
  intervention_text = str_extract(interventions, ":.*[a-z|A-Z].*")
)`
# 2. remove "@" & ":":
`dat$speaker_name <- gsub("@ ", "", dat$speaker_name, perl = T)
dat$intervention_text <- gsub(": ", "", dat$intervention_text, perl = T)`
# 3.use `by` to split `dat` into dfs per distinct ID:
`df_list <- by(dat, dat$speaker_name, function(unique) unique)
df_list`

Comment: Step 2. can be skipped by using positive lookbehind in Step 1.: `dat <- data.frame(
  speaker_name = str_extract(interventions, "(?<=@).*[a-z|A-Z].*:"), # 
  intervention_text = str_extract(interventions, "(?<=:).*[a-z|A-Z].*")
)`

Comment: After a lot of trials of errors I went with this: 

`require(stringr)

dat <- data.frame(speaker_name=str_extract(interventions, "((?<=@)(.*?):)"), intervention_text=str_extract(interventions, "(?<=:).*[a-z|A-Z].*"))
df_list <- by(dat, dat$speaker_name, function(unique) unique)`

which is pretty much exactly what you had given me, except in order to capture only the first colon, I had to improve the regex to this `((?<=@)(.*?):)` which I adapted from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42457235/10665396.

Comment: So I take it you're fine? Or is there anything you need help with?

Comment: Yes, we're fine, thank you so much! I might as well document what I did if anyone else is looking to do the same in the future. The last step was to split the interventions into parties which I was able to do by going `party <- rbind(df_list[["M. Smith :]], df_list[[Mrs. Jones :]])` and listing every speaker for every party, then extracting to Excel spreadsheets with the xlsx package `library(xlsx) write.xlsx(party, "export_path")`